# como hacer mas optimizable mi tabla

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una tabla de seis columnas y quiero agregarle 4 escuadras o filas, el código que hice es este:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $nombre='Holger Angulo';
        $direccion='cll. 115 #08-70';
        $telefono='321 721 8707';
        $fechacumpleaños='29/09/1986';
        $colorfavorito='azul';
        $significado='admosfera, mar';
     //construccion de la tabla
     echo "<table border=1>"; 
     echo "<tr>";             
     echo "<th>NOMBTRE</th>";
     echo "<th>DIRECCION</th>";
     echo "<th>TELEFONO</th>";
     echo "<th>FECHA DE CUMPLEAÑOS</th>";
     echo "<th>COLOR FAVORITO</th>";
     echo "<th>SIGNIFICADO</th>";
     echo "</tr>";
     //lo que va en cada columna
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td> $nombre <t/d>";
     echo "<td> $direccion <t/d>";
     echo "<td> $telefono <t/d>";
     echo "<td> $fechacumpleaños <t/d>";
     echo "<td> $colorfavorito <t/d>";
     echo "<td> $significado <t/d>";
     echo "</tr>";
   echo "<table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quiero agregar otras tres escuadras o filas pero al ver tanto código veo que es muy tedioso yo se que debe haber una forma mas optimizable para no hacer tanta carreta [image: asi me esta quedando hasta ahora]

[image: Asi quiero que me quede]

Comment: En lo que mostras arriba solo hay una fila. Estas escribiendo cada fila a mano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con el uso de [arreglos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) para el mejor manejo de multiples datos:

**ejemplo:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
      $nombre='Holger Angulo';
        $direccion='cll. 115 #08-70';
        $telefono='321 721 8707';
        $fechacumpleaños='29/09/1986';
        $colorfavorito='azul';
        $significado='admosfera, mar';

        // creamos un arreglo
        $data = [
        // opcion 1 "fila 1"            
        [$nombre,$direccion,$telefono,$fechacumpleaños,$colorfavorito,$significado],
        // opcion 2 "fila 2"
        ['Holger Angulo2' ,'cll. 115 #08-70 2','321 721 8707 2','29/09/1986 2','azul 2','admosfera, mar 2'] 
        ];

     //construccion de la tabla
     echo "<table border=1>
             <tr>
             <th>NOMBRE</th>
             <th>DIRECCION</th>
             <th>TELEFONO</th>
             <th>FECHA DE CUMPLEAÑOS</th>
             <th>COLOR FAVORITO</th>
             <th>SIGNIFICADO</th>
             </tr>";

// hacemos un loop para recorrer cada posiciones            
foreach( $data as $filas ){ // recorremos las filas
   // imprimimos el inicio del tr
    echo "<tr>";
   // hacemos un loop para recorrer cada dato
    foreach($filas as $valor){ // ahora los valores de las filas
         // imprimimos cada valor.
         echo"<td>$valor</td>";
    }
    // imprimos el cierre del /tr
    echo "</tr>";
}
// cierrre de la tabla
echo "<table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas hacer es no repetir el cuerpo de tu codigo lo primero que debes hacer es crear un ciclo que repita esa parte de la seccion y los datos lo puedes traer de un base de datos o un array.

Te aconsejo que leas la documentacion para la generacion de array multidimensionales si vas a trabajar con datos estaticos. (en estos link encontraras muchas informacion valiosa para programar tanto HTML, CSS, PHP y JavaScript)

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

Aqui te adjunto el codigo mejorado para resulver el problema:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

 <?php
  // declaracion del array multidimencional
      $datos = array(
          array('nombre'=>'Holger Angulo',
                'direccion'=>'cll. 115 #08-70',
                'telefono'=>'321 721 8707',
                'fechacumpleaños'=> '29/09/1986',
                'colorfavorito'=> 'azul',
                'significado'=> 'admosfera, mar'
            ),
            array('nombre'=>'Alexander Rodriguez',
                'direccion'=>'Caracas',
                'telefono'=>'#999-00099999',
                'fechacumpleaños'=> '12/10/1973',
                'colorfavorito'=> 'azul',
                'significado'=> 'cielo y mar'
            )
      ) 
?>

<table border="1">
    <!-- encabezado de la table -->
    <thead style='background-color: deepskyblue;'>
    <tr>            
       <th>NOMBRE</th>
       <th>DIRECCION</th>
       <th>TELEFONO</th>
       <th>FECHA DE CUMPLEAÑOS</th>
       <th>COLOR FAVORITO</th>
       <th>SIGNIFICADO</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ejecutar cuerpo de tabla -->
        <?php
         for ($i=0; $i < count($datos) ; $i++) { 
        ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['nombre'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['direccion'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['telefono'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['fechacumpleaños'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['colorfavorito'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $datos[$i]['significado'] ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php     
         }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

**Explicacion:**

1) El primer bloque he creado un arreglo multimensional, en el cual el primer arreglo se invoca numericamente y el segundo es de tipo asociativo para mostrar el valor de los campos.

2) He cambiado los echo por codigo HTML para la creacion de la tabla

3) Coloque algo de CSS inline para dar color al encabezado del titulo

4) Dentro de la tabla hay un **bloque PHP** que corre una instruccion `for ()` la cual se encarga de poblar el contenido al recorrer el indice de la tabla y mostrar los valores de cada item.

La salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]